# Can't convert QString to Const Char*

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qstring, const-char

I'm new to QT so please excuse me if I'm blatantly doing something wrong here, but I've looked at all the questions here on the matter but can't seem to find something that works. I'm trying to have the user create a folder by entering a name for it, and it 'creates' a folder with the name. I say 'create' because it's not exactly creating one, it makes a folder first called "project" before you enter the name, and when you enter a name it renames it. However, when I try and rename the folder with the inputted name it gives me

> error:C2664: 'int rename(const char *,const char *)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'QString' to 'const char *'

Here's my code:

```
    void MainWindow::on_actionNew_Project_triggered(const char *parameter)
{
    //Create project folder
    QString projectPath = "D:/Project";

    QDir dir(projectPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkpath(projectPath);
    }


    //Get project name from user
    bool result;
    QString name = QInputDialog::getText(0, "New Project",
                                             "Enter in project name", QLineEdit::Normal,
                                             "", &result);
    if(result && !name.isEmpty()) {

    //Rename project folder to user created name
    QDir dir(projectPath);
        if (dir.exists()) {
            rename(projectPath, name); //Gives me error HERE

        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if you guys could help, I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: This question does not contain an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As the compiler error states, you need two `const char*` arguments, but your `projectPath` and `name` is of type `QString`. `projectPath.toLatin1().data()` could be used as argument. Next time you should include all relevant function declarations i.e. your `rename` method in this case in order being able to help you faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dir.rename(dir.dirName(), name);`

You are trying to invoke a member function without an instance.

Since `rename()` is a member function of `QDir`, you need a `QDir` instance in order to invoke it. So rather than just calling `rename()` which invokes who knows what, you need to `dir.rename()`.

`QDir::rename()` actually takes 2 `QString`s as parameters, but that other function you are invoking takes two raw strings, so you don't really need to convert the strings, you were just calling the wrong function.

```
bool QDir::rename(const QString & oldName, const QString & newName)
```

You are most likely calling `rename()` from `<stdio.h>`, which could also work given that the parameters are correct and the OS can rename the directory, in that case you will need to convert to "raw" C-style strings via `yourString.toLatin1().constData()`. But since you are using Qt, you might as well use the `QDir` API, which works directly with `QString`.

If it still doesn't work, then either your input parameters are wrong, or there is something preventing the OS from rename the directory, for example a file currently in use.

Comment: Well, it stopped giving me the error, but it doesn't rename the folder

Comment: @GuyWhoNeedsHelp - that's a different issue. This question is about converting `QString` to `const char *`. If it doesn't work as expected, then there is something else wrong with your code.

Comment: Seems like you have some more learning to do, not only about Qt but also about C++ in general.

Comment: See the last edit, if that still doesn't work, then debug your code. Check your paths and so on. Just because previously it didn't compile doesn't mean that now execution reaches there. You might be passing the wrong path. There are a number of things that can go wrong, you need to find out what.

Comment: @dtech: Although your solution would be correct in itself, this is not an answer to the question of the questioner. His problem is that he has not shown all the relevant parts of the source code to answer his question correctly. So we can only speculate how his own "rename" method looks like.

Comment: Good answer. Far too many people use non-Qt stuff (and need to coerce their code to do what they need) when Qt provides what they need.

Answer (score 7):

You could call [QString::toStdString()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString%20QString::toStdString()), and then call [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) to retrieve the const char* from the std::string.

Your code would look something like this:

```
if (dir.exists()) {
        rename(projectPath.toStdString().c_str(), name);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Qt FAQ says:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app(argc, argv);
 QString str1 = "Test";
 QByteArray ba = str1.toLatin1();
 const char *c_str2 = ba.data(); 
 printf("str2: %s", c_str2);
 return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I get  "error: C2039: 'toAscii' : is not a member of 'QString'" when I do that

Comment: There is no longer `toAscii()` in Qt, `toLatin1()` is the correct function.

Comment: So try below the section 1 in the answer i says there : `toLatin1();`

Comment: It gives me the error again. Here is my code after doing what you guys said: 

QString a("Asdf");
    const char *c = a.toLatin1();

    //Rename project folder to user created name
    QDir dir(projectPath);
        if (dir.exists()) {
            rename(projectPath, a);

Comment: I basically did "QString a("Asdf");
const char *c = a.toAscii();" but with toLatin1()